# Visual Studio Code - duplicate selection ONLY

Tags: visual-studio-code

There is a solution on how to duplicate a line. But how do I duplicate the selection? Like in Notepad++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This extension worked for me:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lafe.contextualduplicate

I then opened up my Keyboard Shortcuts to assign a memorable binding. In my case, I used `<SHIFT><COMMAND>-D` so it behaves just like Sublime Text.

Answer (score 3):

There is now a dedicated command, with [VSCode 1.40 (Oct. 2019)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_40#_duplicate-selection):

> ### Duplicate selection
>
> We have added a new action named **Duplicate Selection**.
>
> - When executed, the current selection will be duplicated and the result will be selected.
> - When there is no selection, the current line will be duplicated, all without writing to the system clipboard.

You can associate a keyboard shortcut to that command.